# Unable to query postgres using ansible

Tags: windows, postgresql, ansible

I am trying to connect to postgres installed on windows server using ansible but unable to do it.
I am running ansible on my MAC laptop and able to connect to postgres using pgadmin.

When I am running query using ansible, I am getting error.

```
TASK [Access postgresql] ****************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/arun/Learning/ansible-winrm/postgres.yml:9
Using module file /Users/arun/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<5X.2X.X4.X8> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5986 TO 5X.2X.X4.X8
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
fatal: [5X.2X.X4.X8]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"At line:4 char:21\r\n+ def _ansiballz_main():\r\n+                     ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:13 char:27\r\n+     except (AttributeError, OSError):\r\n+                           ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:15 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:15 char:30\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                              ~~~~~~~~~\r\nUnexpected token 'scriptdir' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:15 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing closing ')' in expression.\r\nAt line:15 char:39\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                       ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:15 char:40\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                        ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:7\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:30\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                              ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:22 char:25\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                         ~\r\nThe '<' operator is reserved for future use.\r\nNot all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.\"\r\nAt line:10 char:1\r\n+ $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command \r\nname, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r\nAt line:11 char:2\r\n+ &$exec_wrapper\r\n+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r\n ",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

My `postgres.yml` file looks like below

```
- hosts: windows
  remote_user: Administrator
 
  tasks:
  - name: Access postgresql
    community.postgresql.postgresql_query:
        login_user: postgres
        login_password: mypassword
        query: SELECT datname FROM pg_database
        db: postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors you see are caused by the fact that Ansible is attempting to use PowerShell to execute Python code, which isn't ever going to work. Looking at [the documentation for Ansible on Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_windows.html#what-modules-are-available), it looks as if only a small number of modules are actually supported for Windows:

> ### What modules are available
>
> Most of the Ansible modules in core Ansible are written for a combination of Linux/Unix machines and arbitrary web services, though there are various Windows-only modules. These are listed in the “windows” subcategory of the Ansible module index.
>
> In addition, the following core modules/action-plugins work with Windows:
>
> - add_host
> - assert
> - async
> - debug
> - fail
> - fetch
> - group_by
> - include_vars
> - meta
> - pause
> - raw
> - script
> - set_fact
> - setup
> - slurp
> - template (also: win_template)

That suggests you're not going to be able to run the
`postgresql_query` modules on your Windows host.